# How to make my App appear on my Android Device?

Tags: android, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I use Ionic 3. I would like to test my app on my Android device. 
When I type the command

`ionic cordova run android` this error appears and nothing happens on my device.

How to make my app appear on my Android device?

I am novice. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Please check requirements of project using 
`ionic cordova requirements`  command

Comment: run this as 'ionic cordova run android --stacktrace'  make sure that your device is attached while using this!

Comment: all things are ok in your system for now! by the requirement command! stacktrace will show what is causing this issue! if the other projects of ionic run then this should run too

Comment: No, always the same problem friend this doesnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you have included `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` in your project but you have not enabled `Jack` which is required to support the java 8 language features.

However, jackOptions is deprecated and you have to do it another way. [Ref](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

To fix this, you simply have to update your **Gradle**, **Android Studio** and **buildToolsVersion** to the latest version.

Comment: It worked for me, but I also had to do the Java update.
Thank you very much Jeff !

Answer (score 0):

also you can use "ionic cordova build android --debug"
for testing your app in your device